# Flutter Overlay Window not matching parent size

Tags: flutter

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window .

When calling the overlay, even though I use "MatchParent" for the height, the overlay will be higher and reach out of the safe area.
I have put a background image 'tester.jpg' in to show it easier.

First code is the home page, second is the overlay.

[parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nAJs.png)
[overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baUbF.png)

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_overlay_window/flutter_overlay_window.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static const String _kPortNameOverlay = 'OVERLAY';
  static const String _kPortNameHome = 'UI';
  final _receivePort = ReceivePort();
  SendPort? homePort;
  String? latestMessageFromOverlay;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (homePort != null) return;
    final res = IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
      _receivePort.sendPort,
      _kPortNameHome,
    );
    log("$res: OVERLAY");
    _receivePort.listen((message) {
      log("message from OVERLAY: $message");
      setState(() {
        latestMessageFromOverlay = 'Latest Message From Overlay: $message';
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      bottom: true,
      maintainBottomViewPadding: true,
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('lib/images/holiday/tester.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final status = await FlutterOverlayWindow.isPermissionGranted();
                log("Is Permission Granted: $status");
              },
              child: const Text("Check Permission"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final bool? res =
                    await FlutterOverlayWindow.requestPermission();
                log("status: $res");
              },
              child: const Text("Request Permission"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                       ///CALLING OVERLAY HERE  

            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (await FlutterOverlayWindow.isActive()) return;
                await FlutterOverlayWindow.showOverlay(
                  alignment: OverlayAlignment.bottomCenter,
                  enableDrag: false,
                  flag: OverlayFlag.clickThrough,
                  height: WindowSize.matchParent,
                  width: WindowSize.fullCover,
                );
              },
              child: const Text("Show Overlay"),
            ),

                       ///CALLING OVERLAY HERE   


            const SizedBox(),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final status = await FlutterOverlayWindow.isActive();
                log("Is Active?: $status");
              },
              child: const Text("Is Active?"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await FlutterOverlayWindow.shareData('update');
              },
              child: const Text("Update Overlay"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                log('Try to close');
                FlutterOverlayWindow.closeOverlay()
                    .then((value) => log('STOPPED: alue: $value'));
              },
              child: const Text("Close Overlay"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                homePort ??=
                    IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(_kPortNameOverlay);
                homePort?.send('Send to overlay: ${DateTime.now()}');
              },
              child: const Text("Send message to overlay"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(latestMessageFromOverlay ?? ''),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to put padding on the overlays side, but still it is bigger than the parent.

```
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names, deprecated_member_use

import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_overlay_window/flutter_overlay_window.dart';

class TextFieldOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextFieldOverlay({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TextFieldOverlay> createState() => _TextFieldOverlayState();
}

class _TextFieldOverlayState extends State<TextFieldOverlay> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FlutterOverlayWindow.overlayListener.listen((event) {
      log("$event");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        bottom: true,
        maintainBottomViewPadding: true,
        child: Stack(
            children: [
              Align( 
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                heightFactor: 1, 
                widthFactor: 1, 
                child: Image.asset('lib/images/holiday/tester.jpg',), 
                )
              ),
            ],
          ),
    );
  }
}
```